# Roll up Opportunity Data to Managers

Tags: opportunity-teams

I am working on trying to show opportunity data roll up to managers and above for all the opportunities owned by users reporting up to them. So basically I want the managers to be able to go to a report / dashboard which shows all opportunities that are owned by users reporting up to them.

I have tried implementing this with Territory Mgmt 2.0, where I assigned an opportunity to a Territory A (with User A being the owner of that oppty and he is also assigned to Terr. A) and then I try to run the oppty report while logged in as the Manager (who is assigned to Territory B(parent of Terr. A)). But it doesn't seem to work. Based on what I understand as User B I should have seen the oppty. using "My Team's Opportunities" filter.

Would anyone happen to know what am i missing here ?

Also, any suggestions with other ways to tackle this problem are also appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To show opportunity data roll up to managers and above for all the opportunities owned by users reporting up to them, you don't need to go for Territory Management, this can be achieved using role hierarchy. The reports show the rolled up data automatically. you need to ensure a proper role hierarchy is built and users are assigned to correct roles. Select My Team's opportunities in the report filter.

Comment: Hi Asif, We are not using Role Hierarchy since our data access has to be governed by custom sharing rules.